# Stop systemd service by sending command to screen session

Tags: systemd, gnu-screen

I run [Biglybt](https://www.biglybt.com/) as a daemon inside a screen session using the following command

```
screen -c /home/pi/.screenconf -L -dmS Biglybt_screen /usr/bin/java -cp "/usr/share/java/jna.jar:/home/pi/biglybt_stock/BiglyBT.jar:/home/pi/biglybt_stock/dorkbox-systemtray.jar:/home/pi/biglybt_stock/commons-cli.jar:/home/pi/biglybt_stock/log4j.jar:/home/pi/biglybt_stock/junit.jar:/home/pi/biglybt_stock/swt.jar" -Djava.library.path=/home/pi/biglybt_stock -Dbiglybt.install.path=/home/pi/biglybt_stock -Dazureus.script=/home/pi/biglybt_stock/biglybt -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Ddebug.swtexec=1 -Dazureus.config.path=~/.biglybt_stock  com.biglybt.ui.Main --ui=console
```

And I can stop the daemon by sending `quit` command to the screen session as below

```
screen -S Biglybt_screen -p 0 -X stuff "quit ^M"
```

now I want to make a service file so that when the system shutdown the screen session gets a `quit` command to be exited gracefully

I tried this service file

```
[Unit]
Description=BiglyBt daemon
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=pi
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -c /home/pi/.screenconf -L -dmS Biglybt_screen /usr/bin/java -cp "/usr/share/java/jna.jar:/home/pi/biglybt_stock/BiglyBT.jar:/home/pi/biglybt_stock/dorkbox-systemtray.jar:/home/pi/biglybt_stock/commons-cli.jar:/home/pi/biglybt_stock/log4j.jar:/home/pi/biglybt_stock/junit.jar:/home/pi/biglybt_stock/swt.jar" -Djava.library.path=/home/pi/biglybt_stock -Dbiglybt.install.path=/home/pi/biglybt_stock -Dazureus.script=/home/pi/biglybt_stock/biglybt -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Ddebug.swtexec=1 -Dazureus.config.path=~/.biglybt_stock  com.biglybt.ui.Main --ui=console
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -S Biglybt_screen -p 0 -X stuff "quit ^M"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but when I stop the service, the process just gets killed instead of ending the screen session, So what am I missing?

**UPDATE:**
This service file works

```
[Unit]
Description=BiglyBt daemon
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=0.0
Type=simple
User=pi
Group=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -cp "/home/pi/biglybt_stock/BiglyBT.jar:/home/pi/biglybt_stock/swt.jar" -Djava.library.path=/home/pi/biglybt_stock -Dbiglybt.install.path=/home/pi/biglybt_stock -Dazureus.script=/home/pi/biglybt_stock/biglybt -Dazureus.config.path=/home/pi/.biglybt_stock -Dazureus.overridelog=1 -Dazureus.overridelogdir=/home/pi/biglybtlogs/ -Ddebug.swtexec=1 com.biglybt.ui.Main --ui="console,telnet"
ExecStop=/usr/bin/java -cp /home/pi/biglybt_stock/BiglyBT.jar -Djava.library.path=/home/pi/biglybt_stock -Dbiglybt.install.path=/home/pi/biglybt_stock -Dazureus.script=/home/pi/biglybt_stock/biglybt -Dazureus.config.path=/home/pi/.biglybt_stock  com.biglybt.ui.Main --shutdown
SuccessExitStatus=143
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem now is that i can no longer start the swt ui(gui) of biglybt.
The swt ui can be started either by telneting to the server and issue `ui swt`
or running

```
/usr/bin/java -cp "/home/pi/biglybt_stock/BiglyBT.jar:/home/pi/biglybt_stock/swt.jar" -Djava.library.path=/home/pi/biglybt_stock -Dbiglybt.install.path=/home/pi/biglybt_stock -Dazureus.script=/home/pi/biglybt_stock/biglybt -Dazureus.config.path=/home/pi/.biglybt_stock  -Dazureus.overridelog=1 -Dazureus.overridelogdir=/home/pi/biglybtlogs/ -Ddebug.swtexec=1 com.biglybt.ui.Main --ui="swt" --open
```

which will send request to the main process to start the swt ui.
Unfortunately this runs fine inside regular terminal window but when running the main process inside systemd then this give

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

inside the journal logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@ErikF](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/267846/erikf) and support from biglybt github account I was able to solve the issue, this service file now works for me

```
[Unit]
Description=BiglyBt daemon
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Environment="DISPLAY=:0.0"
Type=simple
User=pi
Group=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -cp "/usr/share/java/jna.jar:/home/pi/biglybt/BiglyBT.jar:/home/pi/biglybt/dorkbox-systemtray.jar:/home/pi/biglybt/commons-cli.jar:/home/pi/biglybt/log4j.jar:/home/pi/biglybt/junit.jar:/home/pi/biglybt/swt.jar" -Djava.library.path=/home/pi/biglybt -Dbiglybt.install.path=/home/pi/biglybt -Dazureus.script=/home/pi/biglybt/biglybt -Dazureus.script.version=9 -Dazureus.overridelog=1 -Dazureus.overridelogdir=/home/pi/biglybtlogs/ -Duser.dir=/home/pi/biglybt com.biglybt.ui.Main --ui="console,telnet"
ExecStop=/usr/bin/java -cp "/home/pi/biglybt/BiglyBT.jar" com.biglybt.ui.Main --shutdown
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Also I created a script to launch the swt(gui interface):

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/java -cp "/home/pi/biglybt/BiglyBT.jar" com.biglybt.ui.Main --ui=swt --open
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't want to use `screen` to daemonize inside of `systemd` because `systemd` assumes certain things about how a process works, particularly in `oneshot` mode. From the [`systemd.service(5)` documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html):

> Behavior of `oneshot` is similar to `simple`; however, it is expected that
>   the process has to exit before systemd starts follow-up units.
>   `RemainAfterExit=` is particularly useful for this type of service. This
>   is the implied default if neither `Type=` nor `ExecStart=` are specified.

Your process isn't exiting immediately, so `oneshot` isn't the correct behaviour to look for.

Looking at `bigly --help`:

```
usage: [options] [torrent [torrent ...]]
 -h,--help        Show this help.
 -u,--ui <uis>    Run <uis>. ',' separated list of user interfaces to run
                  (swt, console, telnet). The first one given will respond
                  to requests without determinable source UI (e.g. further
                  torrents added via command line).
    --closedown   shutdown an existing instance of BiglyBT
    --shutdown    shutdown an existing instance of BiglyBT
    --open        show the BiglyBT interface
    --share       share a resource
```

Bigly is able to start in telnet mode, which should be good enough to run as its own daemon without any extra help; it can then talk to a running instance to send a shutdown command using `--shutdown`. Taking this into account, we can run the service in `simple` mode (I excluded classpath references and command line options that weren't required to run, so add them back if you need them):

**bigly.service**:

```
[Unit]
Description=BiglyBt daemon
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -cp /home/pi/biglybt_stock/BiglyBT.jar -Djava.library.path=/home/pi/biglybt_stock -Dbiglybt.install.path=/home/pi/biglybt_stock -Dazureus.script=/home/pi/biglybt_stock/biglybt -Dazureus.config.path=/home/pi/.biglybt_stock  com.biglybt.ui.Main --ui=telnet
#ExecStop=/usr/bin/java -cp /home/pi/biglybt_stock/BiglyBT.jar -Djava.library.path=/home/pi/biglybt_stock -Dbiglybt.install.path=/home/pi/biglybt_stock -Dazureus.script=/home/pi/biglybt_stock/biglybt -Dazureus.config.path=/home/pi/.biglybt_stock  com.biglybt.ui.Main --shutdown
#SuccessExitStatus=143
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "nc 127.0.0.1 57006 <<< 'quit iamsure'"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

<del>The process exits with an exit code of 143, so I noted that as the success condition for the service.</del> As `--shutdown` doesn't seem to work in telnet mode, I used netcat to send the quit command to the telnet server (port 57006 appears to be the default.) As well, there were a number of error conditions at startup, but I was looking at getting the program running so I ignored them.

The telnet interface binds to all interfaces, so you may want to set up a firewall rule to prevent outside connections.

Comment: I suspect the other problem was that ExecStop is supposed to be synchronous, i.e. the command specified needs to wait for the service to clean up before it returns.  I'm not sure that quitting screen will wait for the contained processes to exit, it probably just closes the PTYs (causing SIGHUP to be sent).

Comment: That's certainly possible. I've never tried using `screen` in a service context before, so I'm a little uncertain about how it interacts with `systemd`.

Comment: I tried running the ExecStart command in one terminal and then the ExecStop command in another terminal but the process still running!

Comment: It appears that the `--shutdown` option doesn't work in telnet mode. Assuming that the server always uses 57006 (that seems to be the default), I've edited the answer to send a command to gracefully shutdown the server rather than use `systemd`'s termination routine.

Comment: When i stop the service i get this in the journal `19:27:43 raspberrypi systemd[1]: biglybt.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=2
Feb 11 19:27:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped BiglyBt daemon.
Feb 11 19:27:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: biglybt.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 11 19:27:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: biglybt.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.`
and the service enters failed status

Comment: @ErikF I used `--ui="console,telnet"` in the ExecStart and `--shutdown` in the ExecStop and this works but I don't know how I can detect if the program is really being ended gracefully, moreover when I want to run the swt ui I get `Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused` in the journal and the service fails

Comment: As it's running in a service, you'll never see the console: that's why I only used `--ui=telnet`. I don't get an error 2 when I stop the service: did you reload the changes using `systemctl daemon-reload`? If it still doesn't work, try using `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh` (and do you have `nc` available?) And for using SWT, you could try with `--ui=telnet --open`, but I can't guarantee that (I did the testing on a headless server.)

Comment: @ErikF `--open` doesn't work with `--ui=telnet`, it works if it was `--ui=swt --open` or just `--open` if the main process already had `--ui=swt`,see the question update please.