# systemd connect to stdin/stdout after service has started

Tags: systemd, io

I have a systemd service that is a console application, meaning that it is controlled by sending commands to its stdin and it outputs information to sdout. How can I set up the systemd service so that I can connect to its stdin and give it commands at any point, then detach from this, and repeat when necessary?

Comment: Shows how - https://askubuntu.com/questions/802189/how-to-run-tmux-screen-with-systemd-230.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423289/stop-systemd-service-by-sending-command-to-screen-session.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I can think of multiple ways to do this. Of course, each has its own caveats.

1. Probably the most straightforward approach would be to create a simple service with a dedicated tty, similar to this:

   ```
   # /etc/systemd/system/systemd-interactive-simple-tty.service

   [Unit]
   Description=Example systemd interactive simple tty service
   After=getty.service

   [Service]
   # https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html
   ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/systemd-interactive.bash
   StandardInput=tty-force
   TTYVHangup=yes
   TTYPath=/dev/tty20
   TTYReset=yes
   # https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html
   Type=simple
   RemainAfterExit=false
   Restart=always
   RestartSec=5s

   [Install]
   WantedBy=default.target
   ```

   The following options will work with the above simple service:

   1. [conspy](http://conspy.sourceforge.net/) takes (remote) control of a text mode virtual console.  This is probably your best bet (with the above tty service).  It's available via most extended package repositories and is simple to use, like this:

      ```
       conspy 20 # hit ESC+ESC+ESC (3 times quickly, to exit)
      ```
   2. [chvt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chvt.1.html) works similarly to `conspy` but makes /dev/ttyN the foreground (local) terminal.  It's part of the [kbd](http://ftp.altlinux.org/pub/people/legion/kbd) collection and is installed by default on virtually every modern Linux distribution.  That's why I thought it was worth a mention.  The major caveat with `chvt` is that it requires you to use the attached keyboard, which is probably not what you want.  For the above service example, `chvt` could be used like this:

      ```
       chvt 20 # ALT+F1 to return to /dev/tty1
      ```
   3. [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) uses the `ptrace(2)` system call to attach to a remote program (via it's PID).  This is a completely different approach than `conspy` & `chvt`, but would work with the above service definition too.

      Just keep in mind that `reptyr`, by itself, doesn't really support 'detaching'.  Its termcap support isn't very robust, either.  Typically, `reptyr` is used in conjunction with [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) and/or [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) because they provide a more seamless way to 'detach'; I find `reptyr` is a great, niche tool to move existing PIDs into a `screen` session or `tmux` window or pane.

      That said; I put this option here, albeit last, because it's still possible to use `reptyr` without `screen` or `tmux`.  The major caveat is if you break out of the process (e.g ^C), rather than reptyr'ing it (again) to another tty/pty (via another shell).  Sending a break to the process may cause it to abort and I'm sure you know the rest.

      Maybe that's OK, especially if the process isn't critical and the systemd service is configured to `Restart=always` as I've shown above.  If the process 'breaks' then systemd will automatically restart it (another cool feature of systemd!).  There are different values for `Restart`, too.  YMMV.

      `reptyr` is available via most extended package repositories and can be used, like this:

      ```
       reptyr $(systemctl status systemd-interactive-simple-tty.service | grep Main\ PID | awk '{print $3}') # or just reptyr <pid>
      ```
2. Another (more complex [meaning there's more that could fail]) approach would be to create a forking service using screen, similar to this:

   ```
   # /etc/systemd/system/systemd-interactive-forking-screen.service

   [Unit]
   Description=Example systemd interactive forking screen service

   [Service]
   # https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html
   ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/screen -X -S ${SCREEN_TITLE} kill # [optional] prevent multiple screens with the same name
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -dmS ${SCREEN_TITLE} -O -l /usr/bin/bash -c /usr/local/sbin/systemd-interactive.bash
   # https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html
   Type=forking
   Environment=SCREEN_TITLE=systemd-interactive
   RemainAfterExit=false
   Restart=always
   RestartSec=5s
   SuccessExitStatus=1

   [Install]
   WantedBy=default.target
   ```

   [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) is a full-screen window manager that multiplexes a physical terminal between several processes.  It's quite a bit more complex than anything listed in the first, simple option.  Personally, I've been using screen for a long, long time and feel comfortable enough to trust it with most things.  It's an invaluable tool.

   The primary advantage over the above is decent termcap support (though not as good as tmux's).  That just means that your backspace key, arrows, etc. will work better than with `conspy` or `reptyr`.  `screen` is available via most *base* package repositories, and can be used like this:

   ```
   screen -r systemd-interactive # CTRL-A+D to detach
   ```
3. A similar approach to forking screen would be to fork `tmux`.  The systemd service for `tmux` is almost the same as it is for `screen`.  But, I'm not going to detail this because, well, it's late & I'm tired.  Yes, I use `tmux` *a lot* more than `screen` (these days).

   In fact, I'm writing this in neovim pane in `tmux` right now.  But, I've still used `screen` for a lot longer.  In my experience and opinion, `tmux` is overkill for something like this.  Sure `tmux` is newer, has more features, and is a MUCH better shell multiplexer than `screen` but ... it's even more complex. Along with that extra complexity comes some additional instability.

   More important, to me at least, is that `tmux` crashes more often than screen.  I listed screen as #2 because, if it were me, for something like that I'd probably just use #1 with `conspy`.
4. Depending on your program; named pipes ... systemd services support them, too! i.e.

   ```
   StandardInput=/path/to/named/pipe|
   ```

... and more.

Comment: first version viz the `type=simple` one: As the [systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) link you have kindly provided says, `GuessMainPID` is ignored if type is simple and so may be dropped.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; I've dropped it from the example.

Comment: Great post (upvote from me) but it's perhaps also worth mentioning `detachtty`. It's a super lightweight `screen`like app, but with none of the additional functionality (just support for detaching and reattaching to ttys).

Comment: I like the screen answer. There's a small typo in the ExecStartPre script though: it should be `-S` for the session name instead of `-t`. In ExecStart, make sure the bash path is correct for your system too (I have `/bin/bash` not `/usr/bin/bash`). Errors starting the screen session may cause it to fail silently.

Comment: Thanks @Quantum7.  I've updated in the ExecStartPre for screen, to use -S rather than -t.

Comment: Three years late in posting a comment here... your answer is so thorough that it ought to have a special place in StackExchange! I'm a *big* fan of `screen`, but the only configuration of `systemd`+`screen` that I could find was specifically tailored for launching Minecraft servers... your solution seems to be much more generic, and, as a consequence, it was quite easy to adapt to my own purposes. Thank you so much!

Comment: Question: why can't use `screen /dev/tty20` to connect to the tty on the first example? It seems to connect but nothing shows while `conspy` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler solution for screen that works for me:

Location:

```
/home/someUser/.config/systemd/user/some.service
```

Content:

```
[Unit]
Description=someServer

Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=screen -S screenName -D -m /home/someUser/startServer.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Can you please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/736241/edit) the answer to explain how exactly this addresses the question? Looks like this isn't really an answer to the question, but rather comment on the accepted answer; and answers aren't for commenting. Please check the Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) and take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get a picture on how Q&A sites work and differ from discussion boards.