# How to control systemd service using screen?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I've set up a systemd service to run my Minecraft server. Now, I need it to repeat the start script when the server crashes.
Here's my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    cd /home/mcserver/Spigot
    echo Starting Spigot...
    echo 600 > ./restart-info
    java -jar spigot.jar
    echo Server has stopped or crashed, starting again in 5 minutes...
    sleep 300
done
```

I can actually view the output of `spigot.jar` using `systemctl status spigot`, but I also want to control the server console, maybe using `screen`.

When I try to do this:

```
screen -S "Spigot" java -jar spigot.jar
```

I'll get the `Must be connected to a terminal` error. This command only works in a terminal (not in a script) and I can attach it using `screen -r`.

Is there any way to "bypass" this screen bug?
I already tried to place `script /dev/null` before the screen command.
I don't want to use screen with -d and -m because it'll run in the background and the script will keep restarting my server.

Comment: Why not use `systemd`s restart feature?

Comment: I'm not sure if restart helps... I want the script to wait until `java -jar spigot.jar` stops. And I also want to run the jar file in screen so I can reattach to it at anytime.

Comment: Why do you need to reattach? You can read the output with `journalctl`. Or do you need to interact with it?

Comment: Yes, I need to interact with it and read the output from `systemctl status spigot.service`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't want to use screen with -d and -m because it'll run in the background and the script will keep restarting my server.

So use **`-D`** instead of `-d` (note the capital case!)

> -D -m   This also starts screen in "detached" mode, but doesn't fork  a
> new process. The command exits if the session terminates.

As `screen` won't fork a new process, it will block while `java` is running, and exit when the server stops.

As a bonus, if you add `-S spigot` you can monitor the output (and even send commands!) from any terminal by attaching to that screen

And... since you're using a systemd service anyway (and you should indeed), why are you doing this restart loop in your script? Let systemd handle that for you using `Restart=always` and `RestartSec=5min`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try this today and let you know. :)

Comment: This is all I need for the server right now. Thanks again!

Comment: -D was best answer for me.thanks.

Answer (score 22):

I suspect you've stumbled on [this blog post](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support-and/1897274-how-to-use-screen-on-your-linux-minecraft-server) which uses `screen` to solve a problem where your minecraft server stops when you `$ java -jar spigot.jar`, then close your ssh or putty session.  That method seems to have become the cannonical answer as to how to run a minecraft server, even though it isn't necessary.

systemd is a totally different (and better) solution to this problem, circumventing the need for `screen`.  You can achieve everything you've done in your script with systemd service options.

---

To run a vanilla minecraft server, create `/etc/systemd/system/minecraft.service` with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/minecraft
ExecStart=java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar /home/minecraft/server.jar nogui
User=minecraft
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Set it to launch automatically after boot with `systemctl enable minecraft`.

You asked about how to control it:

```
$ sudo systemctl start minecraft   # Starts the service if it wasn't running
$ sudo systemctl stop minecraft    # Stops the service
$ sudo systemctl restart minecraft # Restarts the service
$ sudo systemctl status minecraft  # Find out how the service is doing
$ sudo journalctl -u minecraft -f  # Monitor the logs
```

---

This does everything except give you a means to send commands to the console. To do that, we'll set up a file that the server will listen to where you can write your commands by creating the following systemd units:

`/etc/systemd/system/minecraft.socket`:

```
[Unit]
PartOf=minecraft.service

[Socket]
ListenFIFO=%t/minecraft.stdin
```

and `/etc/systemd/system/minecraft.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/minecraft
ExecStart=java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar /home/minecraft/server.jar nogui
User=minecraft
Restart=on-failure
Sockets=minecraft.socket
StandardInput=socket
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now you can send console commands by echoing stuff into that file:

```
echo "help" > /run/minecraft.stdin
echo "/stop" > /run/minecraft.stdin
```

What's also cool is that you can make your own custom sequences of commands and `cat` the entire file into the console.  For example, if you play [UHC](https://gist.github.com/stolksdorf/5936212), you can start a new world, have people log-in, then `cat uhc.commands > /run/minecraft.stdin` to set the gamerules, spread the players, and start the event.

Comment: What a fantastic answer! Finally an elegant (and standard) solution to the server's `stdin` problem!

Comment: This solves a major nuisance for me which I spent many hours trying to clear-up.  Any way I tried to do the service unit with screen or tmux, while it seemed to shut down OK (the six "All chunks are saved" were there), following the log, I encountered multiple exceptions and stack trace messages from the jline console-handling package at shutdown.  When I do it this way, without any multiplexer, the shutdown looks nice and clean.

Comment: I'm not running Minecraft, but something in the same line, and I was wondering... can I have _both_ `stdin` _and_ `stdout` on a `systemd` socket (possibly two, I guess...) and then naively attach to those two sockets and expect to have an interactive pseudoTTY? :-)

Comment: Replying to myself: one possibility of doing that is using a 'helper' command such as `screen` to do the magic: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/454098/102206

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn: Yes that's very possible. Here I used `StandardInput=socket`, but you can also use `StandardOutput=socket`

Comment: use `Type=forking` and no need to create `/etc/systemd/system/minecraft.socket` you can just connect to per usual `screen -r`

Comment: You can add `ExecStop=echo "/stop" > /run/minecraft.stdin` to stop the server gracefully and make sure everything is saved.

Comment: @GertBeukema  I don't have a server to test, but I imagine that the minecraft server will shutdown gracefully on `systemctl stop` in response to the `SIGTERM` that systemd sends to it.  If that's not the case, then this is a really good idea (assuming that the process actually exits when it receives this string).  One issue I see with your command is that you're using the `>` character which is not available to `ExecStop=` lines.  You'll need to run this through a shell:  `ExecStop=sh -c 'echo "/stop" > /run/minecraft.stdin'`.

Comment: If you confirm that minecraft doesn't exit gracefully on `SIGTERM`, and does exit with `"/stop"`, then feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for this, but I won't be able to view output using `systemctl status spigot`.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    cd /home/mcserver/Spigot
    echo Starting Spigot...
    screen -d -m -S Spigot java -jar spigot.jar
    SCREEN_NAME="Spigot"
    while screen -list | grep -q $SCREEN_NAME
    do
        sleep 1
    done
    echo Server has stopped, starting again in 5 minutes...
    sleep 300
done
```

This script will wait until the screen session terminates. I can now view the output or interact with the console using `screen -r` or if I have multiple screen sessions running, I can attach using `screen -D -R "Spigot"`.