# Please Help with Conversion

Tags: scripting, systemd, services

Not too long ago I bought a Raspberry Pi 4B 8Gb and successfully set up PLEX Media Server, using a SATA expansion board.. In an effort to expand my own knowledge, I decided to see if I could add a private Minecraft server for the fun of it, and because my niece and nephew will think I'm a cool uncle.

### Steps I've Completed

1. Swapped Raspberry PiOS for Ubuntu Server 21.04 so Java can take advantage of the entire  bus width(64-bit versus 32-bit).
2. Installed [Liberica's Java 16 JDK](https://bell-sw.com/pages/liberica_install_guide-16/#apt-repository-deb-based-linux-distributions) in preparation for Minecraft.
3. Set up a LEMP server(replaced Apache with NGINX) to make sure the LAN was properly set up.
4. Found the [PineCraft Installer](https://github.com/Cat5TV/pinecraft), so I could automate the steps.
5. The installer script completed successfully, with the following Caveats.

### Caveats

- The installer creates init files.  Ubuntu uses systemd
- The server is run as `$user` which requires a `$password`, or the use of `sudo`, which I don't want to have to do every time

### I Need Help Here

I've taken the `.service` file from [Setting up a Minecraft server using Systemd](https://teilgedanken.de/Blog/post/setting-up-a-minecraft-server-using-systemd/), and turned it into this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server Pinecraft SysV init script conversion attempt
Documentation=https://github.com/Cat5TV/pinecraft

Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
User=minecraft
Group=minecraft
Nice=5
KillMode=none
SuccessExitStatus=0 1

#ProtectHome=true
ProtectSystem=full
PrivateDevices=true
NoNewPrivileges=true
PrivateTmp=true
InaccessiblePaths=/root /sys /srv -/opt /media -/lost+found
ReadWritePaths=/home/minecraft
WorkingDirectory=/home/minecraft
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/screen -dmS PineCraft
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/minecraft/server.sh
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/minecraft/stop.sh
Restart=/bin/bash /home/minecraft/reboot.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

1. I cannot figure out how to "pass" the script result to screen.
2. Screen may always be empty, because the service status shows "Active Loaded/exit."  I'm assuming the `server.sh` script completed, but doesn't stay loaded/running
3. If I run the java line with aiker arguments outside the script, the server starts with no errors

See the `Create the Scripts` section, about 3/4 of the way down of the [install script](https://github.com/Cat5TV/pinecraft/blob/main/install).  I've only ever installed a `.service` file from a package/package manager.  I've never had to write one.

### Update

*Partially Solved*:  This setup uses the following cron job:

`crontab -u ubuntu -l`

> @reboot /usr/bin/screen -dmS Pinecraft /home/ubuntu/minecraft/server > /dev/null 2>&1

`server` is the name of the shell script before I renamed it for my test service.  Aparantly on a fresh install cron doesn't run by default `systemctl | grep cron` returned nothing.  A simple `sudo systemctl enable cron && sudo systemctl start cron` fixed the issue.

**I'm still leaving this open, as I'd like to convert this to a native systemd service**

Comment: I don't understand the need for `screen` - do you need to interact with the process in foreground once it has started as a service?

Comment: [systemd.service documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) can help get you started. It seems like your `.service` is at least missing a `Type`?

Comment: The server is meant to run in the background, but still needs monitoring and/or administration.  See [Step 6](https://www.linuxnorth.org/minecraft/#Step%206%20-%20Optional%20-%20Configure%20Minecraft%20to%20start%20on%20bootup)

Comment: I think this may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/612118/272848