# Debian Service isn't starting file correctly on startup

Tags: shell-script, debian, services

I have a file called `botstart.service` in `/etc/systemd/system` with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start all discord bots (AntiSpam, AutoChat, Nyoko, Helper) and the lavalink server.

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/scripts/start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I started it with `systemctl enable botstart`
and it said that it was enabled.
I rebooted my VPS, but the script wasn't executed.
I did `systemctl status botstart` and it showed this:

```
root@Hetzner-01:~# systemctl status botstart
● botstart.service - Start all discord bots (AntiSpam, AutoChat, Nyoko, Helper)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/botstart.service; enabled; vendor preset:
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2021-10-27 01:37:10 CEST; 50s ago
  Process: 481 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/scripts/start.sh (code=eited, status=0
 Main PID: 481 (code=existed, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 27 01:37:07 Hetzner-01 systemd[1]: STarted Start all discord bots (antiSpam,
Oct 27 01:37:10 Hetzner-01 bash[481]: Started all bots
Oct 27 01:37:10 Hetzner-01 systemd[1]: botstart.service: Succeeded.
lines 1-9/9 (END)...skipping...
● botstart.service - Start all discord bots (AntiSpam, AutoChat, Nyoko, Helper) and the lavalink server.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/botstart.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2021-10-27 01:37:10 CEST; 50s ago
  Process: 481 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/scripts/start.sh (code=eited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 481 (code=existed, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

If I run the script manually, it works, but somehow not as a service, but the service gets executed and the script runs (that's what the service status is telling me.)
Does someone know why?
This is the script code:

```
screen -dmS antispam bash -c "cd /home/AntiSpam; python3.8 main.py"
screen -dmS autochat bash -c "cd /home/AutoChat; python3.8 main.py"
screen -dmS helper bash -c "cd /home/Helper; python3.8 main.py"
screen -dmS lavalink bash -c "cd /home/Lavalink; python3.8 main.py"
sleep 3
screen -dmS nyoko bash -c "cd /home/Nyoko; python3.8 main.py"
echo "Started all bots"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `[Service]` section, you did not explicitly define a `Type=`. This means it will default to `Type=simple`.

The man page says:

> If set to simple, the service manager will consider the unit started immediately after the main service process has been forked off. It is expected that the process configured with ExecStart= is the main process of the service....

In short, your script is the main process.  It starts a bunch of processes, then exits.  `systemd` sees your main process exit, then proceeds to clean up the child processes that no longer have a parent.

Instead you want `Type=forking`.

> If set to forking, it is expected that the process configured with ExecStart= will call fork() as part of its start-up. The parent process is expected to exit when start-up is complete and all communication channels are set up. The child continues to run as the main service process, and the service manager will consider the unit started when the parent process exits. This is the behavior of traditional UNIX services. If this setting is used, it is commended to also use the PIDFile= option, so that systemd can reliably identify the main process of the service.

In this case, your child processes will be allowed to live, even after your script ends.  If you add `Type=forking`, things should work better for you.

---

Note that there are some other problems with your design.  If the only change you make is `Type=forking`, then you still have a few problems:

- If one of the processes ends, systemd may or may not decide that is the MainPID and consider your entire service `inactive (dead)`.  Writing to a `PIDFile=` may help with this, but I suspect you don't intend for any one of these processes to be the MainPID.
- If a process fails, `systemd` may not report a failed state.  It's unclear what should happen to the other processes.

Recommendation 1: split each process into its own service.  Then `Type=simple` will work.  This way, if one service fails, you can detect it and operate on it reliably without affecting the other bots.

Recommendation 2: Add `Restart=on-failure`. This will allow a failed service to automatically restart itself (no human intervention required).

Recommendation 3: Don't call `bash` which calls `screen` which calls `python3`. Just call python directly.  `screen` is a work-around that isn't necessary in a `systemd` environment.

Recommendation 4: To implement that `sleep 3`, you can use an `ExecStartPre=`

Following these recommendations, `nyoko.service` would look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nyoko discord bot

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/Nyoko
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sleep 3
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/Nyoko/main.py
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Recommendation 5:  `sleep` isn't too reliable.  On a good day, it wastes 3 seconds. On a bad day, it isn't enough and your service will fail.  Consider adding `After=lavalink.service` to your `[Unit]` section to ensure `lavalink.service` is started before something that depends on it.  If `lavalink` has some kind of signal to show that it is started (file is created or socket opened), then you can trigger off of that instead.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your answer!
I'm referring to Recommendation 3: If I don't run this in screen, I can't view the console of the bots later, or am I wrong?

Comment: If you want to view the stdout of your bots, then you can use `journalctl -u antispam.service`.  There are other options where you can set `StandardOutput=` to a file.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/612118/272848 for an explanation of how systemd can replace screen

Comment: Hey,
so i followed all of your recommendations, but somehow the journalctl isn't up to date.
If i run my file trough the service, look into journalctl, there are no logs from my python file but if i then stop it, the logs show up. Problem: Journalctl isn't up to date.

Comment: Re: Python not flushing to journal: https://serverfault.com/a/927865/483642

Comment: Thank you so much! You're great!