# How to dynamically create a list of units for a `systemd` target?

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

Newbie `systemd` user here; my apologies if the question seems 'too basic' and would be better asked elsewhere on the StackOverflow ecosystem...

I'm in the process of converting some of my ancient `init` service files, written 12 years ago or so, to `systemd`. Some of those had rather nasty tricks to figure out how to configure a batch of services; I'm not really an *experienced* system programmer, and I'm fond of quick & dirty hacks to get things working as proofs-of-concept... they can always be improved later on.

That said, here is what I'm trying to accomplish: I'm hosting an online virtual world platform (no, it's not Minecraft...) that runs several instances of the same binary, but with different parameters (think shards). This would be rather easy to do if I knew how many instances to launch in advance (i.e. at boot time), or at least what set of parameters they would take, or even if I had an actual list (potentially generated in advance) with that information.

In practice, what happens is the following: there is a special 'configuration' directory (at least that one *is* known in advance!) which has several subdirectories (the number is *not* known in advance!), each named after a specific instance. The name *is* important (i.e. I cannot make things easier by using sequential names, which would make some tricks easier to apply, even assuming that I knew in advance how many subdirectories there are — which I don't!). Imagine that the subdirectory names are city names, for example, `NewYork`, `Chicago`, `LA`, `KansasCity`.

So, schematically, you could think of the overall directory tree as looking like this:

```
game-root-folder 
|
\___ bin
|     \___________ myapp (the actual game engine for each instance)
|     \___________ myapp-single-instance.sh (explained below)
|
\___ config-folder
       \__________ NewYork
       |              \______ config.ini
       |          
       \__________ Chicago
       |              \______ config.ini
       |          
       \__________ LA
       |              \______ config.ini
       |          
       \__________ KansasCity
       :              \______ config.ini
```

(my apologies, I'm not good with ASCII diagrams...)

Assume that each `config.ini` is just a set of GPS coordinates for the city in question (in practice, it's not *much* more complex than that, but what matters is that there are enough items in those files — which might be not written by a human, but generated automatically from a 'managing app' — to make it *very hard* to encode everything in environmental variables), i.e. something which is unique and different from city to city and which is hard-coded into the startup configuration for that city.

In practice, the actual layout is considerably more complex, but this should be enough to explain my issue.

When *not* using `systemd`, but rather launching everything manually from the shell, the task is simple — the command to launch each instance will look something like this:

```bsh
# Call this script with `myapp-single-instance.sh start <city name>`
case "$1" in
    start)
        cd /full/path/to/game-root-folder/bin
        /usr/bin/screen -S $2 -d -m -l myapp \
          --config=/path/to/game-root-folder/config-folder/$2/config.ini
        ;;
    stop)
        # discussed below
        ;;
    *)
        # show usage
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

The non-`systemd` configuration file just had an additional script that would list the contents of that configuration directory and extract the names of the subdirectories, launching the start/stop script for each city name, i.e. something like this:

```bsh
cd /full/path/to/game-root-folder/bin
for CITY_NAME in `ls /path/to/game-root-folder/config-folder`
do
    myapp-single-instance.sh start $CITY_NAME
done
```

As a side-note, to *stop* those instances, one can do:

```bsh
/usr/bin/screen -S $CITY_NAME -X eval 'stuff "quit"\015'
```

(assuming that `quit` is the console command to close that instance)
or, if the above doesn't work for some reason (instance in endless loop, not accepting commands):

```bsh
/usr/bin/screen -X -S $CITY_NAME kill
```

in which case `kill` is a command of `screen` itself, to gracefully terminate itself and whatever is inside it. The last option is sending a `SIGKILL`, of course (also done via the currently existing scripts).

As you can see, if someone wants to add a *new* instance for a new city, all they need to do is to create a new subdirectory, say, `Boston`, and start it with the single-line start/stop script; individual instances can then be stopped or started manually if needed; *new* instances might require manual intervention anyway (putting those `config.ini` in place), so it's okay to expect that there are additional commands to set up a *new* instance — so long as each instance is mostly independent of the others, and does not interact directly with them, there is no need to signal anything to the *existing* instances when adding a *new* one (or removing an existing one). Again, in reality, there is a 'master' instance monitoring server, which does some housekeeping behind the scene, but for the purpose of this question, let's ignore its existence for now.

The above example is trivial to adapt to a `init` scenario.

Now, how to do it under `systemd`? Well, the two-tiered approach seems to fit like a glove to the usage of `systemd` *targets*, launching several instances from a *template*. Here is my naïve attempt, [loosely based on this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/454098/102206) (point 3.), but also on others:

```
; myapp@.service

[Unit]
Description=Game city name %I
After=syslog.target
After=network.target
Requires=mariadb.service mysqld.service
PartOf=myapp.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=myappuser
Group=myappgroup
WorkingDirectory=/full/path/to/game-root-folder/bin
ExecStart=myapp-single-instance.sh start "%I"
ExecStop=myapp-single-instance.sh stop "%I"
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 5
KillSignal=SIGCONT
Restart=always
RestartSec=30s
Environment=USER=myappuser HOME=/full/path/to/game-root-folder/bin
RemainAfterExit=false
SuccessExitStatus=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So far, so good, I'm basically just encapsulating my existing scripts inside the `systemd` configuration.

But now what to do with the target?

```
; myapp.target
[Unit]
Description=Launch all game instances
Wants=myapp@NewYork.service myapp@LA.service myapp@Kansas.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Whoops, I forgot Chicago! See, that's what happens when manually editing configurations...

Basically, I would like to have a *dynamic* way to do that, just like I did with the amazing `` `ls /path/to/game-root-folder/config-folder` `` command — so easy, but so powerful! However, from what I read on the subject, it's not possible to pipe the output of a shell command to the `Wants=...` line — in fact, the only lines that *can* run shell commands are the `Exec...=` ones (for obvious reasons). Tough luck for me!

[Others have struggled with similar issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323914/dynamic-variables-in-systemd-service-unit-files). The solution was to push the logic of selecting what instance to run to environment variables, which could then be 'massaged' and sent to the executable itself. I'm a bit baffled about how such a solution could even be implemented in my case, but it doesn't seem to fit my requirements. In fact, I find it strange that such an 'obvious' use-case — dynamically calling service units from a target (where 'dynamic', in this context, means 'a set of service units for a single executable, of unknown size, where each element may have a different range of parameters, different from each other, and not known in advance') — is not a 'trivial' scenario; perhaps I'm not fully grasping how `systemd` addresses this case?

I have seen two examples where the solution was to include different files (using the  `systemd` override mechanism, i.e. putting files inside `/etc/systemd/myapp.service.d/`), and get `systemd` to search for those additional configurations; or, alternatively, list all the possible instances to be called from the `.target` script, store them either in a file or even into an environment variable. Every time someone adds an *additional* instance, a background-timed process would check the subdirectories for each instance and either return an environment variable with every bit of collected data, or write that to a special file (one would assume that this file would be shared on a well-known spot), and read from it in order to figure out how to start each instance at boot time. Such solutions imply running a background daemon that checks what files are available and refreshes such file(s) before calling the target unit with a reload. Nevertheless, these solutions seem not to work when trying to change the `Wants=..` or `Require=..` lines; it's mostly the `Exec...=` parameters that can be addressed this way (although I saw a few conflicting instructions, where allegedly some `systemd` versions have code that will have a 'dynamic' way of filling in fields...).

Also, note that I would like to retain the ability to start/stop/reload instances *individually*, as well as get them all started at boot time (or gracefully stopped before a mandatory reboot, for instance).

Taking all the above into account, what solution would you recommend?

Thanks in advance and keep up the awesome work in this community!

Cheers,

- Gwyn

Comment: You might look at `man systemd.path` for path activation, i.e. calling a script when a new file appears. It probably just uses inotify.

Comment: Aye, @meuh, I thought that I could 'cook' something with that: the idea would be to launch something that did my magical ` `ls ...` ` and wrote the results... somewhere (a file? env?). However, I'd be still stumped: how to get the _contents_ of that into the `Wants=...` line? Unless, of course, you're suggesting auto-modifying code... eek! 

Comment: As I understand it, a `Wants=` in myapp.target is the same as a `WantedBy=myapp.target` in myapp@.service. They just create a symbolic link in `myapp.target.wants/` when you do `systemctl enable myapp@xxx`, and I'm not sure you are even doing that.

Comment: Oh! So what you suggest is just add all the appropriate symlinks there?... e.g. links like `myapp@Chicago`, `myapp@NewYork` etc.? And every new city would get a new symlink? Hmmm. That definitely sounds _very_ promising!

Comment: If PartOf is part of the service [Unit] then the target shouldn't need Wants; systemd will automatically know what templates have been enabled for the target.  systemctl enable myapp@Chicago (etc) should work with what you have.  If you remove Wants= from the target and systemctl enable myapp and then systemctl start myapp what happens?

Comment: Well, well, so that's how the magic is done... @JosephTingiris, removing the `Wants=` line from the target most certainly **works**, exactly as intended! After your explanation (and, to a degree, @meuh's) it kind of makes sense, too: after all, that's exactly the use case which I would think was commonplace!

Comment: Now I just need to wait for an upcoming (scheduled) reboot to see if it actually worked as intended _when booting the system_ ...

Comment: Well well, it _does_ work indeed. To a degree: I forgot that the main instance actually requires MySQL/MariaDB to have been not only _started_ but actually being _actively accepting requests_ (or else there will be horrible race conditions). However, that's a _different_ issue — one that goes beyond the original question — so I'd accept your answer, @JosephTingiris, if only you wrote your comment as an answer 

Comment: There are too many questions IMHO, and I'm unsure what the actual question is.

Comment: @U.Windl when one is a newbie like myself (well, two years ago), it's often incredibly hard to ask _the_ question, or even _a_ question; that's why I essentially wrote a description of what I intended to do, in the remote hope that someone would at least be able to figure out what exactly I was asking, and therefore what the answer should be!
Had I asked this today, I would certainly do a better job. But thanks to JosephTingiris I managed to get things rolling back then :) (I still have the MySQL issue to fix, but that's a separate issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **PartOf** is part of the service **[Unit]** then the target shouldn't need **Wants**; systemd will automatically know what templates have been enabled for the target.

`systemctl enable myapp@Chicago` (etc) should work with what's in the descrption.

*Remove Wants= from the target* and `systemctl enable myapp` and then `systemctl start myapp` ... what happens?

Comment: "Answers" that contain questions like "what happens if ...?" should be comments, not "answers" IMHO.